# LinearLayout layout_weight = 1, layout_height=0dp only works only in preview?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-linearlayout

I have three linear layouts in a sidebar. I want the first to fill whatever space remains and the other two will specify their height. The problem I'm having is that the first view is not stretching to fill the height at all. See my code below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#FF44807f"
              android:id="@+id/musicSideBar">
    <!-- I want this layout to fill whatever vertical space remains -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FF003938"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- this has a list of ImageView, so I set it to wrap_content -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/sidebarHeader"
        android:id="@+id/mediaControls"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#FF095150"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/play_pause_btn"
            android:src="@drawable/play_icon"
            style="@style/media_button"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/stop_btn"
            android:src="@drawable/stop_icon"
            style="@style/media_button"
            />



        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/prev_btn"
            android:src="@drawable/prev_icon"
            style="@style/media_button"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/next_btn"
            android:src="@drawable/next_icon"
            style="@style/media_button"
            />

        </LinearLayout>

    <!-- A custom view that I specify it's height in onMeasure using setMeasuredDimensions -->
    <jaywhy13.gycweb.components.NowPlayingView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF44807f"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
       />


</LinearLayout>
```

It works like I think it should in Android Studio Preview [image: Android Studio Preview]

But it doesn't work when I run it through the emulator. [image: Simulator]

You can see that for the simulator, the linear layout doesn't stretch at all.

Comment: Have you added top layout child at run time ? like HELO text

Answer (score 1):

layout_weight wont work like this for this to work properly you need to set layout weight to all the layouts inside `LinearLayout` that will fix the height of all 3 layouts which you don't want.

You should just set height of first layout to `match_parent` and next layouts to `wrap_content` and set the gravity of the parent layout to bottom.

This will put bottom most layout first with height wrap_content then it will put 2nd layout with height wrap_content and last the top most layout with whatever height is left

example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#FF44807f"
              android:gravity="bottom"  <!--here-->
              android:id="@+id/musicSideBar">
    <!-- I want this layout to fill whatever vertical space remains -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF003938"
        >
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- this has a list of ImageView, so I set it to wrap_content -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/sidebarHeader"
        android:id="@+id/mediaControls"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#FF095150"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/play_pause_btn"
            android:src="@drawable/play_icon"
            style="@style/media_button"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/stop_btn"
            android:src="@drawable/stop_icon"
            style="@style/media_button"
            />



        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/prev_btn"
            android:src="@drawable/prev_icon"
            style="@style/media_button"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/next_btn"
            android:src="@drawable/next_icon"
            style="@style/media_button"
            />

        </LinearLayout>

    <!-- A custom view that I specify it's height in onMeasure using setMeasuredDimensions -->
    <jaywhy13.gycweb.components.NowPlayingView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF44807f"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
       />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace outer LinearLayout with RelativeLayout. Works for me with `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` in inner view.

Comment: How about the same issue in constraint layout